# Child view controller retained after being removed from parent

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, retain

In a Swift project targetting iOS 12, I have a child view controller which is being retained after being removed from its parent (and after its view is removed from .superview).

Xcode's Memory Debugger shows this:

[image: Xcode memory debugger screenshot]

The selected object at the right (IAIARViewController) is the one that is unexpectedly retained. I assume that the dark lines/arrow indicate a strong reference and the light grey ones (e.g. from SCNRenderer) a weak reference, implying that culprit that is retaining the instance is ViewController's _childViewControllers NSMutableArray storage.

However, when I print the description of the NSMutableArray (the one closest in the chain to the IAIARViewController instance), I get:

```
Printing description of $20:
<__NSArrayM 0x112e12370>(
    <***.IAIChartViewController: 0x113226400>,
    <***.IAIMapViewController: 0x113093400>
)
```

i.e. there's no instance of IAIARViewController in the array (and the contents are what I would expect.)

This seems potentially like bad information from the Xcode Memory Graph Debugger. What else could be causing IAIARViewController to be retained?

Comment: You can turn on malloc debug and run the app to record the retains and releases and read them in the memory graph. Also check for leaks.

Comment: Thanks Matt - mallocs look exactly as expected (just the one instance), and no leaks shown in either the Memory Graph Debugger or Instruments. I'm suspecting either Storyboards or SceneKit being used in multiple view controllers right now. Depending on the sequencing, I sometimes see an instance retained by _externalObjectsTableViewForLoading (an internal UIViewController property), or by  C3DEnginePipeline (something in the guts of SceneKit/Metal).

Comment: Did you got any solution for this problem because i do have this problem.@StephenT

Answer (score 0):

You can try to comment one by one the properties (vars) of the controller and find out if it still retained by them. I think the problem is on one of these properties.

Also to check leaks you can use the instruments (look at the screenshots). It can give you more detail information.[image]

Comment: Thanks Nik - which view controller do you mean, and why do you think that a property var might be the issue?

Comment: I suggest, that some property of the retained VC produce the retain cycle.

Comment: OK - I don't see anything in the memory graph debugger (or Instruments/Leaks) that suggests that it's either a leak (no exclamation mark) or a retain cycle (no cycle shown), per se. It's more like an unexplained retain, so to speak. I'll keep digging!